# Keep getting null from previous page

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

I have no idea why it keep returning null from my dialog class. I expect when I click save in PopUpDialog, I will get `return`, but it return me null.

```
ListTile(
      tileColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
      onTap: () async {
        await PopUpDialog()
            .showSigntature(context, color, strokeWidth, _sign)
            .then((onValue) {
          print(onValue);  // I get null
        });
      },
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
      trailing: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.check,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
      title:
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text("Signature"))),
```

**PopUpDialog**

```
Future showSigntature(
      BuildContext context, var color, var strokeWidth, var sign) async {
    await showGeneralDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        barrierLabel:
            MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
        barrierColor: Colors.black45,
        transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation animation,
            Animation secondaryAnimation) {
          return Center(
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            side: BorderSide(color: const Color(0xFF1BC0C5))),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          Navigator.pop(context, "return");
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Save",
                          style: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xFF1BC0C5)),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ],
                )),
          );
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your just forgot to return the value returned by `showSigntature`. Here you go:

```
Future showSigntature(
      BuildContext context, var color, var strokeWidth, var sign) async {
    return showGeneralDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        barrierLabel:
            MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
        barrierColor: Colors.black45,
        transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation animation,
            Animation secondaryAnimation) {
          return Center(
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            side: BorderSide(color: const Color(0xFF1BC0C5))),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          Navigator.pop(context, "return");
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Save",
                          style: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xFF1BC0C5)),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ],
                )),
          );
        });
  }
```